# Not sure how to add a geocoder

Tags: android, geolocation

As my first project, I'm trying to create a small weather app. I know there's a lot of resources but nothing seems to work for me here. So I got this code that makes the Lat+Long appears on my screen when I click a Button, but I can't seem to find the right explication on how to create a Geocoder and throw in the GPS coordinate. I've read similars question on here and also the Android page on Geocoding, but every time it seems the code begins to fail on me.

```
package fr.eni.android.geoweather;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton button;
    private TextView textView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                textView.append("\n " + location.getLatitude() + "" + location.getLongitude());
            }


            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivities(intent);

            }

            private void startActivities(Intent intent) {
            }
        };
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET
            }, 10);
            return;
        } else {
            configureButton();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    configureButton();
                return;
        }
    }

    private void configureButton() {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 500000, 30, locationListener);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the fetchAddressButtonHandler, that code is key, is what you should use in your onclick, but the entire article should help you.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

I hope it helps,

Juan

Answer (score 0):

Check this how to add geocoder

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "us");
        Geocoder g = new Geocoder(mContext, locale);

        List<Address> addresses1 = g.getFromLocation(yourlatitude, yourlongtiude);
        assertNotNull(addresses1);
        assertEquals(1, addresses1.size());

        Address addr = addresses1.get(0);
        assertEquals("94305", addr.getFeatureName());
        assertEquals("Palo Alto, CA 94305", addr.getAddressLine(0));
        assertEquals("USA", addr.getAddressLine(1));
        assertEquals("94305", addr.getPostalCode());
        assertFalse(Math.abs(addr.getLatitude() - 37.4240385) > 0.1);
```